# How to make SystemRescueCD (Arch Linux) mount exFAT?

Tags: arch-linux, exfat

My [SystemRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/) (bootable CD based on [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) distribution) won't mount my exFAT SD card. When I plug in the USB reader, `/dev/sdc` appears, but it won't even show `/dev/sdc1`. No way to mount it, `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/1` will fail.

It is interesting that `/dev/sdc1` is recognized by `cfdisk /dev/sdc` - it shows that there is a free space of ~ 1 MB and then the `/dev/sdc1` of ~ 64 GB. But there is no `/dev/sdc1` appearing on the filesystem! If I put normal FAT SD card in the reader, the `/dev/sdc1` appears correctly.

**How do I make SystemRescueCD mount exFAT?** Looking in `/root/packages-list.txt`, it contains `exfat-utils 1.3.0-1`. I was able to run `mount.exfat` and `mount.exfat-fuse`, but still there is the problem that `/dev/sdc1` doesn't exist, and trying to mount /dev/sdc obviously results in an error.

It is rather surprising, that SystemRescueCD isn't able to do this by default, the purpose of "rescue CD" implies to me that it should be able to mount as many filesystems as possible).

(I have SystemRescueCD version 6.0.3, `uname -a` gives *Linux sysresccd 4.19.34-1-lts #1 SMP Sat Apr 6 19:41:19 CEST 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux*; [it doesn't seem](https://www.system-rescue.org/Changes-x86/) that this issue would be different in the newest version)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of the file system on the device, which you want to mount. Unfortunately, the `mount` command won't do it for you automatically. So, in case of exFAT, you should do something like this:

```
[root@sysrescue ~]# mkdir -p /mnt/windows_dest
[root@sysrescue ~]# mount -t exfat /dev/sdc1 /mnt/windows_dest
```